# Open a Local link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where I am linking all the URLs in a Text in a Hyperlink. But when a user types www., then the browser takes it as a local URL and binds the link to the applications URL.

I want to know how to open local URL in a new Tab.

```
var replaceTextWithURL = systemNotificationText.replace(/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi, function(text, link) {
  console.log(text, link);
  return '<a href="' + link + '" class="systemNotificationExtLink" target="_blank"> ' + link + ' </a>';
  //var httpUrl = link.startsWith("http");
  //var httpsUrl = link.startsWith("https");

  //if (httpUrl || httpsUrl) {
  //    return '<a href="' + text + '" target="_blank" class="systemNotificationExtLink"> ' + text + ' </a>';
  //}
  //else {
  //    return '<a href="http://' + text + '" target="_blank" class="systemNotificationExtLink"> ' + text + ' </a>';
  //}
});
var newLineText = replaceTextWithURL.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
$("#systemNotificationPreview").html(newLineText);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you refine your question, it is not pretty clear what you are asking for?

Comment: When you add a href="www.google.com". it would append after the website URL. eg.stackoverflow.com/google.com. The link does not open in a new window.

Comment: I have given an explanation/answer. please check.